# Iterator implementation causing infinite loop

Tags: java

I am trying to do a foreach loop as followed for a linkedlist-esque class I built:

```
boolean contains = false;
for(Thing t : front) {
    if(t.equals(something)) {
        t.doSomething();
        contains = true;
        break;
    } 
}
```

This are the iterator methods I've implemented:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Thing> iterator() {
    Thing current = this;
    return new Iterator<Thing>() {
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current.hasNext();
        }

        public Thing next() {
            return current.next;
        }
    };
}
```

I've tried debugging this and it seems it isn't returning the next element in the linkedlist, thus causing an infinite loop when I run it and try and do a foreach loop.

Sorry if this question has been answered or there's a really stupid mistake, I searched for a while and couldn't find an answer. This is my first time writing an iterator so please be gentle. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to advance the `Iterator`'s state in `next()` :

```
    public Thing next() {
        current = current.next;
        return current;
    }
```

Otherwise, all calls to `next()` would return the same element.

EDIT :

You should move your local variable declaration `Thing current = this;` inside your anonymous class instance (i.e. turn it into an instance variable).

```
@Override
public Iterator<Thing> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Thing>() {

        private Thing current = Thing.this;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current.hasNext();
        }

        public Thing next() {
            current = current.next;
            return current;
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an error in Eclipse: "Local variable current defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final".

I tried changing the next method to the following:

public Thing next() {
 Thing tmp = current;
 tmp = current.next;
 return tmp;
}

But it is still not advancing to the next element in the list.

Comment: @Tbs95 An anonymous class in a method does not have alteration rights on variables inside the enclosing method. You need to make the `current` variable an instance variable of the `Iterator`, because it is part of the iterator's state.

Comment: Thank you @Eran, but now that I have changed the variable declaration location, I am getting a Type Mismatch error converting new Iterator<Thing>(){} to Thing.

Comment: Gosh, I swear I already tried that and it gave me a different error... Worked flawlessly though, thank you!